# avi audio speed?

Tags: playback

Why does my audio sound like the chipmunks talking when i play an avi file on media player or realplayer or quicktime? How can i adjust the playback speed?

Comment: just a particular AVI or all?

Answer (score 1):

In the past I have seen this happen when vids are re-encoded if the audio sample rate changes without resampling. if you are re-encoding videos and changing the sample rate (e.g. 44.1k, 22k, etc), be sure that you are resampling the audio as well... if not, you can get chipminks or andre-the-giant effects.